# Unexpected symbol ;', expecting)'- an error in C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Helo, I am building a camera in Unity 3D using C# and I keep getting an error stating:
Assets/OVR/Scripts/Util/OVRPlayerController.cs(477,59): error CS1026: Unexpected symbol `;', expecting`)'

Here is my code:

```
if (Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.L)) {
        oldPosition = transform.position;
        newPosition = transform.position + transform.forward *        lerpDist;
        journeyLength = Vector3.Distance(oldPosition, newPosition);
        startTime = Time.time;
        lerpPosition = true;
    }

    if (lerpPosition) {
        float distCovered = (Time.time - startTime) * lerpSpeed;
        float fracJourney = distCovered / journeyLength;
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(oldPosition, newPosition, fracJourney);
        if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, newPosition) &lt; lerpEnd) lerpPosition = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, newPosition) &lt; lerpEnd) lerpPosition = false;
```

Should be

```
if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, newPosition) < lerpEnd) lerpPosition = false;
```